# How do you show the handles of paths (bezier curves) in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I click many times on a point of a path in Gimp, and no handles show up... how do I make them appear?

(I'm using Fedora 16.)

Comment: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Bezier_Selections/ - Under the title **Modifying the curves**.

Comment: put this comment as an answer so OP can chose and close this question

Comment: yeah, it's not working for me... So it must be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Lollero linked to, I should press Ctrl when clicking the points of the path to show the handles, though it doesn't work for me (must be a bug).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the tool option "Polygonal" is unchecked! It prevents you from creating any curves.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63173)

Comment: I believe this does answer the question. I think that if OP unchecks the tool option "Polygonal", the handles will appear, solving OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it seems like an intermittent bug.  The solution for me was to restart GIMP and try the process on a clean canvas.  After it worked there, it worked on my original image.

Answer (score 0):

interestinglythere solution was the one I was looking for. Ctrl and Alt have different functionality dependent on what is selected in the Paths Menu (Design, edit, move). I also found that you can delete an anchor point by selecting edit mode and use shift. You can add an anchor point to an existing path in edit mode.